# Lining up fields in a form

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

I'm having trouble lining up all the fields in my form neatly. Any suggestions?

I want the outside edges of the three input fields to line up with eachother, and the space between the fields vertically to be the same as the space between the name and email fields... Thanks for the help! :)

```css
form {
  background-color: #3d549a;
}
input {
  border: none;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px
}
textarea {
  height: 10em;
  resize: vertical;
  font-family: avenir;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  width: 860px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px
}
.buttonblue {
  padding-left: 90px;
  background-color: #31b9e9;
  font-family: avenir;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 1px #21a1c6
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" style="background-color: #3d549a" height="820px">

  <tr height="250">
    <td valign="bottom" align="center" width="100%" colspan="4">
      <span style="font-family: avenir; font-size: 40px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 500; line-height: 10px;">GET IN TOUCH<span/>
      <hr color="#273a72" width="75" align="centre">
      <span style="font-family: avenir; font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 100; line-height: 10px;">1600 Pennslyvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500, United States of America. Tel: (202) 456-1111</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td <td width="100%" align="center">
      <form class="form" action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
        <p>
          <input class="required" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" style="font-family: avenir; font-weight:100; font-size: 17px; background-color: #273a72;" />
          <input class="required" type="email" id="mail" placeholder="Your Email" style="font-family: avenir; font-weight:100; font-size: 17px; background-color: #273a72;" />

        </p>

        <p>
          </br>
          <textarea class="required" id="msg" placeholder="Your Message" style="font-family: avenir; color: #fff; font-weight:100; font-size: 17px; background-color: #273a72"></textarea>

        </p>
        <p>
          </br>
          </br>
          <button class="buttonblue" type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
          </br>
          </br>
          </br>
          </br>
        </p>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I suggest not building your website in a table. It may seem like it helps you to keep everything in its proper place, it will limit your website design in the end

Comment: Hmmm, okay, thanks! I'm super new to this! If not a table - what then?

Comment: @TomNijs Actually, using a table to layout **forms** is quite common as many developers consider the fields to be tabular data. Now I'm not saying that other options don't exist but it **is** a viable option.

Comment: What i would say is..don't use `br` tags for spacing, that's what padding & margins are for. Make sure you move as much of that inline styling out to a CSS stylesheet. It makes debugging much easier.

Comment: Also, `valign` and `align`not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Comment: @Paulie_D I agree that it is a common and viable strategy. I suppose my education limited scope of possible strategies. :)

Comment: Thanks you two! Input very much appreciated! 

Yes, I'm not very comfortable with CSS, but man it seems to make everything so much easier! Definitely need to focus more on that. 

And no wonder my aligning techniques didn't seem to work ever :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Based upon comments...

Couple of issues with your original code.  First, I'm not sure why you wrapped everything in `<p>` tags (maybe this is from a CMS or something?), but getting rid of that and the extra `<br>` between elements will give you much better fine control over the distance between them using css properties like margin and/or padding.

Additionally, you have a lot of inline styles/deprecated code such as `valign` and `align`.  Consider moving all of this to your external CSS and cleaning that up.

Finally, a simple way to align things in your example is to use a table.  Not everyone would agree with using a table for layout unless you are aligning tabular data, however it is easy to use.

Doing all of the above might yield you with something like the following jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ka43prwu/3/

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm not really sure why I did either... I took out all the <p> and <br> tags, and used margin-bottom/top to get the spacing I want instead. 

However, the two top fields won't seem to line up with the sides of the message field :( 

I made a fiddle if you have any suggestions!

https://jsfiddle.net/kmcf89/ka43prwu/

Comment: .... But the fiddle shows it complete different than what my browser does... For some reason the boxes are on two separate lines in that view. Definitely not what I was going for, sorry!

Comment: That's because they are wrapping in the smaller viewport.  If you want to always prevent that, give your table cell a static width, perhaps 865px in this case since that's the width of your largest element (the textarea)

Comment: Oh I see, you made some other changes that made the inputs no longer line up, which is why they wrapped in the smaller viewport.  Ultimately, the answer is you need to adjust your CSS now that you've removed the excess elements.  You could also take off the width styles from the inputs and textareas, put each one of them in their own table cell and then just size the table cells to get them to line up as well, though there will be people on here who tell you not to use tables for layout unless you're displaying tabular data :)

Comment: Something like this might be a better layout: jsfiddle.net/duffmaster33/ka43prwu/2

Comment: Ahhhh thanks you @duffmaster33! That looks much better! This was actually an assignment to get accepted into a coding course - that I got accepted to today :) so thanks for your help!!

Comment: Sounds great, good luck!  You might want to consider marking this as the accepted answer if I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the attribute
display: inline-block;

Comment: Use different cells in table for each field